# $H_q\left(\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^m B_i\right) = 0$ if $q > n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, manifolds, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

In order to prove that $H_q(M) = 0$ if $q > n$ if $M$ is an $n$-manifold the proof in my notes goes like this:

Suppose $M$ is non compact otherwise the thesis is trivial: it's a known fact that $H_q(M,M \setminus K;G) =0 \,\forall q > n$ (already proved).

If $M$ is non compact pick a compact $K \subset M$, then $K = \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^m K_i$ where each $K_i$ is a subset of some $B_i$ homeomorphic to an open ball.

Then we can write $B_i = \mathbb{S}^n \setminus K_i$ for some $K_i$ compact and conclude that $H_i(B_i) = 0$ using the known fact cited above.

I don't understand how by induction using Mayer-Vietoris we should have $H_q\left(\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^m B_i\right) = 0$ since we don't know if the intersection has trivial homology because it seems we don't have control on it, $B_i$ could live in different $\mathbb{R}^n$'s.

Any help or solution in order to clarify this detail would be appreciated.